# Raise Exception when child record found

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I have a plsql procedure to delete records from child and parent tables.

I would like to raise exception when child record found.

How can I do this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc(
    p_id       number,
    p_id2      number,
    p_par3      number)
AS
BEGIN
 DELETE FROM   child_table
            WHERE   id1 = p_id and par=p_par3;

    DELETE FROM   parent_table
            WHERE   no = p_id2;
COMMIT;

EXCEPTION   
    WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
        --raise
END myproc;
/
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the exception block if you don't want to catch the exception !

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc(p_id NUMBER, p_id2 NUMBER, p_par3 NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM child_table
    WHERE id1 = p_id
      AND par = p_par3;

   DELETE FROM parent_table WHERE no = p_id2;
   COMMIT; /* do you really want to commit in a procedure? */
END myproc;
```

You don't have to catch them all ([exceptions are not pokemon](http://www.dodgycoder.net/2011/11/yoda-conditions-pokemon-exception.html)). If you really insist on catching and re-raising you can use [RAISE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/exceptions.htm#TTPLS200) or [RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/exceptions.htm#TTPLS202):

```
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      raise_application_error(-20001 /* user-defined exception number 
                                        between -20999 and -20000 */,
                              'your user-defined exception message',
                              TRUE /* this will preserve the error stack */
                              );
END;
```

If you want to be more specific and trap only the child exception, you will have to [define the exception](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#i3329) number because there is no [predefined exception](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/timesten.112/e21639/exceptions.htm#TTPLS196) in PL/SQL for this error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE myproc(p_id NUMBER, p_id2 NUMBER, p_par3 NUMBER) AS
   child_exists EXCEPTION;
   PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(child_exists, -2292); /* raises ORA-02292 */
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM child_table
    WHERE id1 = p_id
      AND par = p_par3;

   DELETE FROM parent_table WHERE no = p_id2;
   COMMIT; /* do you really want to commit in a procedure? */

EXCEPTION
   WHEN child_exists THEN
      -- do something
      RAISE;
END myproc;
```

Comment: is it possible to have something like this in myproc? `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT(foreign_key_violated, -02291);`
Could you be kind enough to suggest what would happen if commit exists in a procedure?

Comment: Sure, although I think a delete will raise an `ORA-02292`, see my update. For further reading on user-defined exceptions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#i3329

Comment: COMMIT ends the transaction, and should only be decided by the calling application (if not PL/SQL) or by the top-most procedure/statement (if application is PL/SQL). Committing frequently by intermediate procedures breaks the transaction flow (for example batch processes become un-restartable in case of an error mid-batch). See [this discussion on askTom](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4951966319022) for example.

Comment: Yes you are right, I have a `executeUpdate` from my application. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to raise exception when child record found

```
create or replace procedure myproc(p_id number, p_id2 number, p_par3 number)
as
begin

   delete from child_table
    where id1 = p_id
      and par = p_par3;

   if sql%rowcount > 0 then
      raise_application_error(-20001, 'Child record(s) found!');
   end if;

   delete from parent_table where no = p_id2;

end myproc;
```

HTH.

Alessandro

PS: modified my answer for reading comprehension deficiency, I thought you wanted and exception when child record NOT found.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Vincent Malgrat solution has fixed resolved my problem. Appreciated.